# C++: Is it safe to move a jpeg around in memory using a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, jpeg

I have an `external_jpeg_func()` that takes jpeg data in a char array to do stuff with it. I am unable to modify this function. In order to provide it the char array, I do something like the following:

```
//what the funcs take as inputs
std::string my_get_jpeg();
void external_jpeg_func(const char* buf, unsigned int size);


int main ()
{
    std::string myString = my_get_jpeg();
    external_jpeg_func(myString.data(), myString.length() );
}
```

My question is: Is it safe to use a string to transport the char array around? Does jpeg (or perhaps any binary file format) be at risk of running into characters like '\0' and cause data loss?

Comment: Safe? Probably. But misleading. I'd recommend a vector<char> if you just want a contiguous byte buffer.

Comment: When loading from char* the string will stop at null character, so it's not safe.

Comment: @Dani: Not if it is given an explicit length.

Comment: @okorz001 Didn't catch your meaning till after I read the other answers.

@Dani
@NicolBolas I understand it is important to give it an explicit length. However, the usual methods of `string.length()` and `strlen()` seem to fail if there happened to be a null character somewhere in the char array. Any tips?

Comment: @Morpork: `strlen` should not be considered a "usual method" when dealing with binary data that could contain nul characters. That's *why* it's important to have an explicit length, because `strlen` only tells you the position of the first nul.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use `std::vector<char>`, instead of `std::string`, in this case; the danger with `std::string` is that it provides a `c_str()` function and most developers assume that the contents of a `std::string` are NUL-terminated, even though `std::string` provides a `size()` function that can return a different value than what you would get by stopping at NUL. That said, as long as you are careful to always use the constructor that takes a size parameter, and you are careful not to pass the `.c_str()` to anything, then there is no problem with using a string here.

While there is no technical advantage to using a `std::vector<char>` over a `std::string`, I feel that it does a better job of communicating to other developers that the content is to be interpreted as an arbitrary byte sequence rather than NUL-terminated textual content. Therefore, I would choose the former for this added readability. That said, I have worked with plenty of code that uses `std::string` for storing arbitrary bytes. In fact, the C++ [proto compiler](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) generates such code (though, I should add, that I don't think this was a good choice for the readability reasons that I mentioned).

Comment: +1: but I like `std::vector<unsigned char>` even more. `char` still conveys some semantic related to characters (glyph, text), while `unsigned char` is closer to the `byte` concept.

Comment: @6502: if the API you work with is specified in terms of `char`, you just have to bite the bullet...

Comment: @6502, in this case I would disagree; most POSIX functions that require byte buffers take type "char*" or "void*"; it's quite rare to see such functions take type "unsigned char*". In order to avoid potentially confusing or dangerous casts, I would prefer to just be consistent with those and use "char".

Comment: @Matthieu, Micheal Aaron Safyan: I missed the part where it's said that `external_jpeg_function` cannot be touched. Of course if it wants a `char *` then `std::vector<char>` is IMO the best choice.

Comment: @6502: Yes, it's just unfortunate that so many "byte" APIs are specified in terms of `char`, when `char` can be signed or unsigned depending on the compilers' settings :/

Comment: @6502: I thought the whole point of having a `char` type that's separate from both the signed and the unsigned version was to allow IO operations to work in terms of `char`s and allow the platform to choose its most appropriate version. So `char` doesn't mean "glyph", but "the platform's basic data unit".

Comment: One practical "technical advantage" to `std::vector<char>` is that it is not optimized for the sorts of uses that `std::string` is: in particular, many implmentations of `std::string` keep around a short static buffer in the case that the string is quite short (I think this is something to do with avoiding dynamic allocation and/or improving locality of reference), which for the given application would be a (tiny) waste of memory. :)

Comment: You may be right about `vector` doing a better job of communicating to other developers that it isn't nul-terminated data, although if developers did a better job of understanding how the `string` class works, they would be equally good ;-p

Answer (score 6):

`std::string` does not treat null characters specially, unless you don't give it an explicit string length. So your code will work fine.

Although, in C++03, strings are *technically* not required to be stored in contiguous memory. Just about every `std::string` implementation you will find will in fact store them that way, but it is not technically required. C++11 rectifies this.

So, I would suggest you use a `std::vector<char>` in this case. `std::string` doesn't buy you anything over a `std::vector<char>`, and it's more explicit that this is an array of characters and not a possibly printable string.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, I went and created a vector of jpeg images to feed into `external_jpeg_func()` one by one. Is it advisable to have a vector of vector of char?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to use char array char[] or std::vector<char>. This is standard way to keep images. Of course, binary file may contain 0 characters.

Comment: Actually the specification for std::vector says that the memory must be continuous inside the object. So if you have a std::vector<char> image(10); and use "&image[0]" then it returns a memory-array at least 10 bytes long.